# Try/Catch in powershell running sql script

Tags: powershell, try-catch

I'm new to powershell and trying to use the try/catch command in handling the error message.

```
$Output = Invoke-SqlCmd -ServerInstance $dbinstance -username $dbusername -password $dbpassword -Database  $dbname -Query $Query

$isconnected = ''

if ($Output.uri -eq '0' ) {
$isconnected = $true
Write-Host -Foreground Green $isconnected

}else  {
$isconnected = $false
Write-Host -Foreground Red $isconnected
}
```

This is the error I get, but the result remains true even though the outcome should be error because I'm trying to figure out how to catch the error.

[image: Error]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to implement a [`Try` / `Catch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally?view=powershell-7.2) in your script you would need to put your code to query the Database inside the `Try` block and how you want to handle the error in the `Catch` block:

```bash
try {
    $param = @{
        ServerInstance = $dbinstance
        Username       = $dbusername
        Password       = $dbpassword
        Database       = $dbname
        Query          = $Query
    }
    $output = Invoke-SqlCmd @param -ErrorAction Stop
    Write-Host 'Connected' -Foreground Green
    # rest of your code goes here
}
catch {
    Write-Warning $_.Exception.Message
}
```

You might also benefit from [Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-7.2).

`$_` in the context of the `Catch` block represents the caught error, which is an instance of [`ErrorRecord`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.errorrecord?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0). You might want to check the other properties aside from [`Exception`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.errorrecord.exception?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0#system-management-automation-errorrecord-exception).